# How to use FIND() on a list element in python/BeautifulSoup - Im getting Nonetype Error

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

Ok so this code works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(MY SITE URL SITS HERE)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile.read())

title = soup.find('p', {'class': 'deal-title should-truncate'}).getText()  
print "Title: " + str(title)
```

But the above code only gives me the first result. I want to be able to loop through the whole site for each find occurrence. To do that, I tried using a comprehensive loop to find every time a figure tag comes up (since this paragraph tag always comes between a figure tag). This way I can only focus on the contents of whats in figure. However when i try the below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(MY WEBSITE URL SITS HERE)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile.read())

deals = [figure for figure in soup.findAll('figure')]

for i in deals:
    title = i.find('p', {'class': 'deal-title should-truncate'}).getText()  
    print "Title: " + str(title)
```

I get this ERROR:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\blah.py", line
>   11, in 
>       title = i.find('p', {'class': 'deal-title should-truncate'}).getText() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'getText'

Now I am trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import urllib import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(MY SITE SITS HERE) soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile.read())

deals = soup.findAll('figure')

for i in deals:
    title = i.find('p', {'class': 'deal-title should-truncate'})
    if (title == None):
        title = "NONE"
    else:
        title = title.getText()
    print "Title: " + str(title)
```

And now the error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\blah.py", line
>   16, in 
>       print "Title: " + str(title) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 12: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Comment: That means there is at least one `<figure>` that doesn't have a `<p>` in its subtree with the given classes.  The list compehension for `deals` is unnecessary by the way.  `deals = soup.findAll('figure')` would give you the same result.

Comment: @BlackJack you are correct about the list comprehension being unessecary, and I thank you. The first result does return a NONE in the list when I remove the .getText... But then I am left over with a whole bunch of "<p>sometext</p>" is there a way to make sure that I get only the text each time?

Comment: @BlackJack something like this isnt working:
for i in deals:
    title = i.find('p', {'class': 'deal-title should-truncate'}).getText()
    if (title == None):
        title = "Hello"
    else:
        print "Title: " + str(title)

Comment: You'll have to add a step to get the title.  First search the `<p>` element and check if _that_ is `None` before you try to get the text from it. Maybe showing an example of the document structure makes it easier for us to give advice.

Comment: Updated with the step we talked about. It works for the first NONE and then the second (which has a value) but then throws an error @BlackJack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer and special shoutout to **BlackJack** for the help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(MY SITE SITS HERE)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile.read())

deals = soup.findAll('figure')

for i in deals:
    title = i.find('p', {'class': 'deal-title should-truncate'})
    if (title == None):
        title = "NONE"
    else:
        title = title.getText()
    print "Title: " + title
```